# When trying to post FB actions, I get an id but nothing gets posted

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

This is my code

```
   window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId      : 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx', // App ID
          status     : true, // check login status
          cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
          xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
        });

        // Additional initialization code here
      };

      // Load the SDK Asynchronously
      (function(d){
         var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
         if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
         js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
         js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
         ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
       }(document));

       function postscore(){
        FB.login(function(response){
          if (response.authResponse)
          {
            var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
            FB.api('/'+uid+'/xyznamespace:actionname?access_token='+response.authResponse.accessToken, 'post', { objectname: document.location.href, customproperty: 85, 'fb:explicitly_shared':true }, function(response1) {
              if (!response1 || response1.error) {
                alert(response1.error.message);
              } else {
                alert('Post ID: ' + response1.id);
              }
            });          
          }
        },
        {scope:'publish_actions'});
        return false;
      }
```

I am getting a response id, but no post is getting created. What am I doing wrong?

Also, can I pass property values as I have done? Or will that just get ignored?

(The id is returned irrespective of whether I pass a property value or not.)

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Check your activity profile on facebook.com – does the action show up there?

Comment: Yes, I checked, its not there, nor on my timeline, and when I try to open the post directly using the id returned I get a 'page not found' error.

Comment: Does it show up when you use the Graph API Explorer and check `/me/xyznamespace:actionname` there? (Make sure to chose the right app in the dropdown at the top first, because only the creating app can see it’s published actions.)

Comment: Yes! It's returning several posts. Why aren't they in my activity feed?

Comment: OK, then technically everything seems to have gone well. So maybe Facebook just does not display your published action because your app is not “important” enough yet (to small of a user base). Or another reason might be the setup of your action in your app’s settings – do you have _Story Text_ and _Story Attachment_ configured in a meaningful way for your action …?

Comment: I think I have them configured properly. But I have used the custom property in several places, and I see in the API explorer that it's missing. I just hardcoded a value for it using a meta tag, but it's still not working. Also, I'd ideally like to pass it in the API call. Is that possible?

Comment: CBroe, you were right, I changed the story format and it started working.

Comment: @ranioli  I am facing the same issue, can you give more details about what story format you changed. thanks

Comment: Sorry, i don't really remember :s But I think it has to do with the action settings.

Answer (score 0):

Try to get the post by get method and the same ID and check whether the post is coming back. It may be a reason that the post is not visible to you.